# Identify a horror sci-fi story where a mad scientist creates grotesque creatures by combining genes from human and animals

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, horror

Note: I need to start with some introductory information because that might give a clear picture.

I am from India. The story which I am mentioning here was translated in a local language (Bengali) of an eastern state in Indian Union. It was published by local publishers. The original name of the story was not mentioned, but the translated name in the local language literally meant **Evil Creator**. The publishers, however, mentioned the name of the original author.

**The story:**

The protagonist of the story was invited by a scientist to assist him in his experiments on a remote island. The protagonist arrived at the island. The first shocking thing he encountered was a chauffeur who came to receive him at the dock of the island. He had horribly disfigured face- having two elongated scars on both of his cheeks. His voice was harsh and gave an idea that he had some altercation in his vocal chord too. When asked, he revealed his name, which the protagonist found similar with a deceased singer. When questioned, the chauffeur admitted that he is the singer and that he had a horrible accident and that the scientist saved his life.

Upon entering the castle on the island, the protagonist gradually witnessed the grotesque experiments the scientist was carrying out. At first, he witnessed a garden in the castle where the plants were horrific. It had flowers which had strong resemblance with "skull". Instead of a pleasant scent, the flowers emitted a bad pungent odor. Gradually, the protagonist realized the nature of the experiments the scientist carried on. There were horrific creatures, humanoids who were half human and half animal (something like dog-man, panther-man), two-headed dogs, etc.

The scientist had held a beautiful lady captive, whom the protagonist mentioned as the only creature "beautiful and natural" in this "horror-world" of the mad-scientist. The lady secretly told the protagonist about her actual identity- she was an actress who was rumored to have committed suicide.

A romantic feeling evolved between the protagonist and the "damsel in distress". The lady gave all the information about the scientist. The scientist had achieved tremendous success in his experiments of creating new grotesque creatures by combining genes, and sometimes body-parts, of different creatures. However, he failed in achieving the same success while experimenting the same with plants. The experiments on the plants didn't bear the desired results. That's why the protagonist was invited to the island: to help the scientist on his experiments on plants.

The scientist had sensed the "romantic feeling" between the lady and the protagonist. So he declared that both of them will be married off on a "pious" day. Till then, they won't see each other as that would bring "bad omen" on the couple.

On the day of the marriage, the scientist, the protagonist, the strange creatures (who were slaves), etc., all gathered for the event. After the couple were declared husband and wife, the scientist asked the groom to kiss his bride. When the protagonist unveiled the bride, he was shocked to see a deformed face: no eyelids, no lips, scars on face, etc. Clearly, the bride was "operated on".

The protagonist acted repulsive and the scientist ordered his slaves to carry him to OT, so that he could operate on the groom to make him "suitable for the bride". In the ensuing chaos (I don't remember exactly), somehow the protagonist fought back and when the scientist tried to shoot him, the deformed bride jumped on the scientist and somehow they both died (either by falling down from stairs or something).

Then as a surprise, the protagonist saw the "real lady" coming running towards him. She revealed that the "deformed bride" was mad-scientist's wife whom he hated very much and tortured her.

The two then returned to mainland and started a new life.

---

The story has a striking resemblance with H.G.Wells' "***The island of Doctor Moreau***". However, there are some differences too:-

1. The protagonist in Wells' novel was rescued after a shipwreck by the
   assistant of Dr. Moreau. In this story, the protagonist was invited
   by antagonist himself.
2. AFAIK, there was no "romantic relationship"
   in Wells' novel.
3. In Wells' novel, Moreau tried to convert animals to
   humans. In this story, the antagonist's main objective was to create
   hybrid animals.
4. AFAIK, Moreau was not hostile to protagonist.
5. "The Island of Doctor Moreau" was a novel. This one is a "short story".

What is the name of the story?

**Extra note**:

1. The author's name was **Vernon Ruth** (that's what I made up from the
   local translation).
2. The protagonist's name was **James**.
3. The mad scientist was called **Diaz Volo** or **Daiaz Volo** or **Daiaz Bholo**.  Since the story was written in local translation, hence I don't know the exact spelling. It spelled as **Daiaz Volo** in local language.
4. The female lead was probably named **Beatrice Skelimore**, though in local translation her name was spelled **Beatriche** (pronounced as `ch` from `chocolate`).
5. The scientist had an apprentice/slave called **Kuilp**.
6. The chauffeur's name was **Porteous Malloy**.
7. The name of the island was mentioned as **Bufrey**.
8. The translated name of the story literally meant "**Evil Creator**".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The original story is named "**[The Black Creator](http://www.booksquawk.com/2011/09/second-pan-book-of-horror-stories.html)**" by **Vernon Routh**. It was one of the stories published in "**The Pan Book of Horror Stories**" edited by **Herbert Van Thal**.

> Vernon Routh’s “The Black Creator” is an amiable slice of hokum about an expert in plant life being lured to a strange island to do a job for a mad scientist. The villain hates beauty and will do anything to corrupt it – taking an especial pleasure in mutilation and suffering, as well as the odd bit of genetic tinkering. Examples of his handiwork haunt the grounds of the castle he lives in, weird half-human half-animal hybrids. So naturally, you fear the worst when our noble narrator meets Beatrice the sexy chamber maid.
>
> Sadly this wasn’t the carnivorous plants tale I thought it would be; it is, however, a bonkers pulp-style story with more than a passing nod to HG Wells’ Island of Dr Moreau. It’s disturbing enough and ends with a nightmarish mock wedding, but I have to confess I found some details, such as the dog-faced security guard, unintentionally funny.
>
> And perhaps it’s appropriate for a story about someone who wants to destroy beautiful things that there are parts where the lovely English language is corrupted. First off, a contender for the worst simile of all time: “Walking to the resident’s lounge was like treading on aerated foam rubber in an opulently perfumed and warmed stillness.”

This was probably the only story from the author in his entire lifetime, and that's why this guy is so unknown.

Comment: Nice self answer. I'd be curious as to how you ended up finding it!

Answer (score 6):

Depending when you read it, it could be a story in Gene Wolfe's collection
The Island of Doctor Death and Other Stories and Other Stories (1980) 
with the story of the same name.

The other option I have is *The Isles of Dr. Moreau* from 2015, which is

> by Heather O'Neill in her short story collection Daydreams of Angels.
>   It tells of a grandfather who, when he was young, meets an eccentric,
>   albeit humane scientist named Dr. Moreau on "the Isle of Noble and
>   Important and Respectable Betterment of Homo sapiens and Their
>   Consorts". Moreau's experiments involve combining animal DNA with
>   human DNA and the story unfolds as the grandfather meets (and dates)
>   several of these humanoid creatures.
>
> Source: [Wikipedia article on *The Island of Doctor Moreau*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Island_of_Doctor_Moreau)

But I can't confirm either one at the moment.

If someone has better fits, that would be awesome.

Comment: http://www.wolfewiki.com/pmwiki/pmwiki.php?n=Stories.TheIslandOfDoctorDeathAndOtherStories for the first.

Comment: There have also been a few remakes of the Isle of Dr. Moreau, such as Chalker's "[The Moreau Factor](https://www.amazon.com/Moreau-Factor-Jack-L-Chalker/dp/1522684123)."